Can the science of logic exist when there are no commonly accepted objective philosophical facts?
Philosophy distinguishes itself with the science of logic. But if other branches of science always have a set of commonly accepted facts as well as commonly accepted unknowns/assumptions, in philosophy you practically have only opinions that often contradict each other. So, how can the science of logic exist when there are no commonly accepted objective philosophical facts?

"Philosophy distinguishes itself as a science of logic" What does it mean?

"Is the main (divine) purpose of logic in philosophy to hide (obscure) factual truth from a wider population? " Really?

Narrowed the Q&A to a single question. Feel free to roll back.

We need a close option for "this question is based on such an egregiously false premise that it cannot be rehabilitated."

Leaving aside the political discussion, I agree with David Gudeman that it would be very helpful to have an additional close option for those questions which show such dramatic and fundamental misunderstandings that it would be better to address the misunderstandings than to answer the question. This particular question isn't one of the big offenders, but there are a lot of them on Phil.SE.

You ask:

Can the science of logic exist when there are no commonly accepted objective philosophical facts?

Yes, because logic is inherently a normative science about the application of reason to any fact, and therefore it is not dependent on philosophical facts per se. Or scientific or mathematical facts for that matter. Consider the analogy of philosophy to logic in the same way we can compare reason to the logical form of an argument.

P1. Socrates is in the kitchen.
P2. The kitchen is inside the house.
C. Therefore Socrates is in the house.

While we may be talking about Socrates and various facts related to how space is organized in houses, the logic is a structure independent of the facts. Since logic is the study of what follows from what, the validity of this argument has nothing to do with Socrates or houses at all because it is what is recognized as a transitive relationship.

P1. X < Y
P2. Y < Z
C. Therefore X < Z

This is the same idea that in deductive logic we have a difference between a sound and valid argument. Logicians, as long as they agree on the validity of an argument, can have different takes on the soundness of arguments, because logic shows less concern for the truth of particular premises. Taken to the extreme, logic also then becomes a portal into a variety of possible worlds, where premises are actually varied with the logician keeping an eye on the properties of logic when certain aspects of logic are held constant.
Thus, philosophers can disagree and adjudge all manner of facts as true or false as they see fit, but are able to have important conversations using counterfactuals, hypotheticals, and conditionals since the question of what is fact is but one aspect of human reason. On a practical note, however, you may be making too much out of the factual disagreements of philosophers, as modern professional philosophers tend to accept many of the same theories despite their individual differences. Modern secular philosophers ascribe a lot of facticity to evolution, the scientific method, the formal sciences, and physicalism for instance. To be honest, most philosophers probably agree on most things, and the case for factual relativism is overstated.

P1. Socrates is in the kitchen.
P2. The kitchen is inside the house.
C. Therefore Socrates is in the house. - And Socrates house is in a computer game. And ...

If that kitchen, in that house, is in a computer game, yes. And if any of the steps turns out to be false, all the steps derived from it are correctly false. (Stoner drawl: "Socrates ain't here, man.")

Today’s logic calculi are conceived as axiomatized formal systems similar to calculi like set theory or other mathematical theories.
Logic does not presuppose philosophical theories. It is just the opposite way: Philosophy uses logic as a means for correct argumention, in general in quite modest form.
That there are few general accepted philosophical results has several causes:

Philosophy speaks about anything and everything.
And the relations between philosophical concepts with their broad
scope are not as well defined as the relational concepts in logic or
mathematics.

The results of philosophy cannot be checked - confirmed or refuted - like scientific results.

"Philosophy speaks about anything and everything", "The results of philosophy cannot be checked" - In plain language, it means "Anything goes". If, in an empirical science, a lot of prior research and publications are dead, in Philosophy almost nothing is dead, and any ancient argument can be retrieved and used in modern discussion.

To answer the question, yes. Formal logic is a set of rules for manipulating ideas. Logic recognizes that those ideas may be false, and ensures that the manipulations will yield an appropriate result in that case. The tool is the tool. What results you get out of it depends on what you put into it. If you get what you think is an unreasonable result, check the inputs, check the operations, and check your assumptions. If you find a genuine flaw in logic, publish.

"set of rules for manipulating ideas" - If you cannot be sure what is "true" or what is "false", how can you agree on a commonly accepted set of rules? How can you have rules without known facts?

The same way you agree on rules of algebra. You establish rules that work whether the values are true or false, producing the appropriate result in each case. You can then manipulate things using conditional assumptions -- variables -- to get conditional results in terms of those assumptions. Remember that the goal here is not to prove the assumptions, it's to understand the implications of the assumptions.

"keshlam" - Did you see mathematicians arguing for millennia  that 2+2=4 ?

For they normally assumed values of each of those symbols, that is a true statement.  If you change the assumptions the result can change.  Personally, since I know what most of us mean by those symbols, I consider going into the exceptions pointless except when those contexts are explicitly specified, but you do you.
